# Linking problems with 64bit db2 db2api.lib truncated to fit errors

Tags: gcc, db2, cygwin, 64-bit

I have 64 bit installations of db2 express and cygwin. I am trying a very simple test up and running:

gcc ex1.o -o ex1.exe ../../sqllib/lib/db2api.lib

../../sqllib/lib/db2api.lib(DB2APP64.dll.b):(.text+0x2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__imp_sqlastrt' defined in .idata$5 section in ../../sqllib/lib/db2api.lib(DB2APP64.dll.b)
../../sqllib/lib/db2api.lib(DB2APP64.dll.b):(.text+0x2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against symbol`__imp_sqlaaloc' defined in .idata$5 section in ../../sqllib/lib/db2api.lib(DB2APP64.dll.b)
../../sqllib/lib/db2api.lib(DB2APP64.dll.b):(.text+0x2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__imp_sqlasetdata' defined in .idata$5 section in ../../sqllib/lib/db2api.lib(DB2APP64.dll.b)
etc..

I tried all -mcmodel options to no avail. Other than that I couldn't find much in the way of solutions to this problem. What do I need to do to get this to link correctly?

(same problem as prior post, but after much searching it seems that others have got something very similar to the above to work, presumably on 32 bit machines)

Comment: What is wrong with this question? None of the other questions related to this topic that I had read through has solved it. Can anyone shed some light as to why IBM's db2api.lib doesn't link out of the box on a 64 bit system the way it apparently does on 32 bit systems. I fail to follow why this isn't a legitimate question to try to find an answer for. Please comment and I will try to follow whatever advice you give.

Comment: For example, the only high rated page on this type of error points to a solution that is applicable only if you are writing assembler. That is not the case here. It is simple C program (perhaps I should have mentioned that, but gcc normally implies C if nothing else is said). So what solutions are there to this problem? I could change the compiler or the database, but an informed response would be better before attempting either.

Comment: What do you know? I solved it. Now if someone says what is wrong with the question, I will update as necessary. I really didn't expect that to work, btw, but then when you run out of options, you try everything.

Comment: Is building with Cygwin actually even supported by IBM?

Comment: It works fine with 32 bit db2, which is what I resorted to after my fix above turned out not to be good enough (it got it to link and run without error, but results were later wrong).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `binutils` version 2.24, I suspect the problem to be this: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16598

Luckily, the Cygwin port of GNU `ld` is capable of linking directly against DLLs.  Specifying the relevant DLL(s) rather than the import library `db2api.lib` to `gcc` should work.

Comment: Thanks. My solution for linking and executing was to link directly against the DLLs (which I really hadn't expected to work). However, the results I got from the program later on ended up being incorrect. I ended up doing the work on a 32bit DB system using the same approach as I had tried for the 64 bit one. So the problem is still outstanding in terms of being able to link IBM's 64 bit DB2.